Как скрыть узлы с панели удаленного дерева Godot
Добавила на сцену Color Picker Button, при нажатии на который соответственно появляется панель выбора цвета, но такой вид меня не устраивает, хочу убрать все нижние ползунки, но как это сделать?

Самый очевидный способ обращаться к ним с помощью get_child() и скрывать. Но get_child не находит узлы на удаленном дереве сцены, только на локальном (либо я что-то делаю не так).
На Color Picker  Button вешаю такой скрипт, но не срабатывает
for i in this_node.get_children():
        i.hide()

Как можно скрыть ноды из удаленного дерева? Ну либо убрать ползунки каким-то другим способом

# инициазируем кнопку
@onready var button = $ColorPickerButton

func _ready() -> void:
    # Получаем окно выбора цвета
    var popup = button.get_picker()

    # Отключаем не нужные ползунки
    popup.color_modes_visible = false
    popup.hex_visible = false
    popup.presets_visible = false
    popup.sampler_visible = false
    popup.sliders_visible = false

Все доступные для редактирование ползунки, можете почитать в документации (ссылка)


